# How can I run c# code from a button click?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I made a program in C# and was using a hardcoded reference to the *Program Files* directory whilst making the program. I'd now like to remove the hardcoded reference.

I have been recommended this method from Eric on stackoverflow in a recent topic. However, I wasn't able to understand how to run the code from a button_click:

**Eric said:**

```
string programFilesFolder = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

**Continuing that example you could do something like this**

```
string pathToFile = 
    Path.Combine(programFilesFolder, @"TEST\ok.txt");

if (File.Exists(pathToFile)) 
    File.Delete(pathToFile);
```

To be 100% honest with you all, I am newish to c# and am still learning...

Can someone please give an example on how to invoke the code above from a button_click? I am going to be doing this to more than one file using the same button.

I did ask this question in a comment on the other thread, but I think they all moved on.

Comment: **Protip:** You dont need to check if the file exists before deleting. In fact, if you needed to do so, you will have a possible race condition.

Comment: True, however after the file is deleted i will copy a file from my install folder to TEST and it will be same file name as ok.txt. I would edit the above however i am quoting someone elses post so..

Comment: What is the problem in using the method in  button click? why not use `Path.Combine(programFilesFolder, @"TEST\ok.txt")` where you hard coded the path before?

Comment: I'm just a bit confused. If i used Path.Combine(programFilesFolder, @"TEST\ok.txt") then how would it know the programFilesFolder? don't i have to insert all of the above into the C#? Thats what i don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to make a Windows Forms application to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w2f38k(v=vs.90).aspx

That will show an example of how to do a Windows Forms example where you can drag a button onto a canvas and then have a click action on the button.

In the example it says to put

```
MessageBox.Show ("Hello, World!")
```

but you could put the code to delete the file there instead and it will delete whatever you want to delete on the click of the button.

```
string programFilesFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
string pathToFile = Path.Combine(programFilesFolder, @"TEST\ok.txt");
File.Delete(pathToFile);
```